# Handle exceptions in .net remoting objects

Tags: .net, remoting

I am working on a .Net Remoting project. If there is any exception in remote object, I would like to send that exception in detail to the client. I am using the following code to accomplish that-

```
'This is on a shared .dll
Public Interface ICreateNewMouza
Function CreateNewMouza(ByVal MouzaToCreate As Mouza) As Integer
End Interface

Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<serializable()> _
Public Class CustomException
Inherits System.ApplicationException

Public Sub New(ByVal message As String)
    MyBase.New(message)
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
    MyBase.New(info, context)
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub GetObjectData(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
    MyBase.GetObjectData(info, context)
End Sub
End Class

'This is remote object which a client will invoke-

Imports System.Runtime.Remoting
Imports ClassInterfaces

Public Class CreateNewMouza
Inherits MarshalByRefObject
Implements ClassInterfaces.ICreateNewMouza

Public Function CreateNewMouza(ByVal MouzaToCreate As ClassInterfaces.Mouza) As Integer Implements ClassInterfaces.ICreateNewMouza.CreateNewMouza
    Try
       ' some code
    Catch ex As Exception
      ## what should be here?
    End Try

End Function
End Class
```

What should be in the try.. catch block? Did i miss something else?
Please help me.

Thanks in advance
SKPaul

Answer (score 0):

You've got it right there - the exception you'll catch is a [RemotingException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingexception.aspx). I've always preferred WCF to remoting, but it appears you've set things up correctly in your example.

Are you getting a particular problem, or it something not working correctly, or are you just asking out of curiosity as you're setting setting things up?

Comment: Dear rwmnau, 
First thing is, i could not send the exception to client. But i am able to collect the exception in that remote object. Now, how to send to client? Perhaps, i dont know the correct way to do it.

Comment: @SKPaul. Simply throw your custom exception in the Try/Catch block. Your client will receive an exception of type CustomException. To add additional information to your exception add a property to your class and serialize/deserialize it in the releated functions/constructors.

Comment: Hansjoerg, 
I dont want to throw any exception. But if any exception occurs, i want to catch it and convey it to the client. Hope, you have realized my intention.